# Почему не работает скрипт из видео-урока?

Tags: javascript

Делал по [видео уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1AUOszVo2M) фильтр контента, переписал все символ в символ а оно не работает, помогите решить проблему, в консоле ничего нету.

```js
const filterBox = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

document.querySelector('nav').addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  if (event.target.tagName !== 'LI') return false;
  let filterClass = event.target.dataset['f'];

  filterBox.forEach(elem => {
    elem.classList.remove('hide');
    if (!elem.classList.contains(filterClass) && filterClass !== 'all') {
      elem.classList.add('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.block4 a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block4 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 6px 7px 28px 0 rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.7);
  min-height: 140px;
  min-width: calc(22% - 28px);
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-width: 3px;
  float: left;
}

.box.alizarin {
  border: 3px solid #e74c3c;
}

.box.wisteria {
  border: 3px solid #8e44ad;
}

.box.emerland {
  border: 3px solid #2ecc71;
}

.box.belizehole {
  border: 3px solid #2980b9;
}

.box.sunflower {
  border: 3px solid #f1c40f;
}

.text-alizarin {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.text-wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.text-emerland {
  color: #2ecc71;
}

.text-belizehole {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.text-sunflower {
  color: #f1c40f;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: a1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes a1 {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block4">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li data-f="all">ALL</li>
        <li data-f="alizarin" class="text-alizarin">ALIZARIN</li>
        <li data-f="wisteria" class="text-wisteria">WISTERIA</li>
        <li data-f="emerland" class="text-emerland">EMERLAND</li>
        <li data-f="sunflower" class="text-sunflower">SUNFLOWER</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="block-cover">
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box sunflower"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box sunflower"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box sunflower"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё работает: Тег скрипт должен быть где-то после HTML. Он запрашивает элементы, которых еще нет на странице.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно дождаться пока DOM-дерево будет построено, для этого можно "привязаться" к событию [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) или разместить сам скрипт перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`:

```css
.block4 a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block4 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 6px 7px 28px 0 rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.7);
  min-height: 140px;
  min-width: calc(22% - 28px);
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-width: 3px;
  float: left;
}

.box.alizarin {
  border: 3px solid #e74c3c;
}

.box.wisteria {
  border: 3px solid #8e44ad;
}

.box.emerland {
  border: 3px solid #2ecc71;
}

.box.belizehole {
  border: 3px solid #2980b9;
}

.box.sunflower {
  border: 3px solid #f1c40f;
}

.text-alizarin {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.text-wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.text-emerland {
  color: #2ecc71;
}

.text-belizehole {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.text-sunflower {
  color: #f1c40f;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: a1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes a1 {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const filterBox = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

  document.querySelector("nav").addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    if (event.target.tagName !== "LI") return false;
    let filterClass = event.target.dataset["f"]

    filterBox.forEach(elem => {
      elem.classList.remove("hide")
      if (!elem.classList.contains(filterClass) && filterClass !== "all") {
        elem.classList.add("hide")
      }
    })
  })  
  })
</script>

<div class="block4">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li data-f="all">ALL</li>
        <li data-f="alizarin" class="text-alizarin">ALIZARIN</li>
        <li data-f="wisteria" class="text-wisteria">WISTERIA</li>
        <li data-f="emerland" class="text-emerland">EMERLAND</li>
        <li data-f="sunflower" class="text-sunflower">SUNFLOWER</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="block-cover">
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box sunflower"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box sunflower"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box sunflower"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box alizarin"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box wisteria"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box emerland"></div>
      <div class="col-auto box belizehole"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, дело было в бутстрапе